# Como logro editar desde un form un archivo secundario? en Excel VB

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Que tal tengo el siguiente codigo para mostrar archivos en una ubicacion especifica lo que quiero lograr es que cuando se abra ese archivo, el userform2 que cuenta con una caja de texto identificada como txtescaneo el cual nos ayuda a ingresar los datos a la hoja de excel lo haga pero en el archivo que acabo de abrir desde el listbox pero mi problema recide en que cada vez que ingreso los datos los registra en el excel donde se creo la macro y no en el archivo que acabo de abrir desde el listbox.

espero puedan ayudarme

```
UserForm1

Public selectedWorkbook As Workbook
Public openedFromListBox As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ' Ruta de la carpeta que contiene los archivos
    Dim carpeta As String
    carpeta = "\\tsshared2\KaizenJMC\5. ALBERTO CRUZ\RegistrosTriwall\Pendientes\"

    ' Lista de archivos en la carpeta
    Dim archivos As Object
    Set archivos = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder(carpeta).Files

    ' Agrega cada archivo al ListBox
    Dim archivo As Object
    For Each archivo In archivos
        ListBox1.AddItem archivo.Path
    Next archivo
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    ' Asigna la ruta del archivo seleccionado a la variable global
    selectedFilePath = ListBox1.Value
    
    ' Abre el libro desde el ListBox y almacena la referencia
    Set selectedWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(selectedFilePath)
    
    ' Establece la variable para indicar que el libro fue abierto desde el ListBox
    openedFromListBox = True
    
    ' Oculta el UserForm1
    UserForm1.Hide
    
    ' Muestra el UserForm2
    UserForm2.Show
End Sub

UserForm2

' Declarar variables globales
Dim filaActual As Integer
Dim columnaActual As String
Dim maxRegistros As Integer

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ' Configurar variables globales
    filaActual = 22
    columnaActual = "B"
    maxRegistros = 52
    
    ' Al abrir el segundo formulario, mostrar los datos desde las celdas en etiquetas
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    ' Verificar si el archivo fue abierto desde el ListBox
    If isUserForm2Open Then
        ' El archivo fue abierto desde ListBox
        Set ws = selectedWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Else
        ' El archivo no fue abierto desde ListBox
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    End If

    ' Resto del código para inicializar el UserForm2
    ' ...

End Sub

Private Sub TxtEscaneo_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

' Manejar el evento KeyDown para mantener el enfoque en el TextBox
If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then

    ' Variable para la hoja de trabajo
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    ' Verificar si el archivo fue abierto desde el ListBox
    If openedFromListBox Then
        ' El archivo fue abierto desde ListBox
        Set ws = selectedWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        
        ' Verificar si ya se alcanzó el máximo de registros
        If filaActual > 47 Or (filaActual = 47 And columnaActual = "D") Then
            MsgBox "Se completaron los 52 registros disponibles para el primer triwall.", vbInformation
            TxtEscaneo.Value = ""  ' Limpiar la caja de texto después de alcanzar el límite
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' Insertar el dato escaneado en la celda correspondiente
        ws.Range(columnaActual & filaActual).Value = TxtEscaneo.Value
            
        ' Mostrar el dato en el ListBox
        ' ListBoxDatos.AddItem TxtEscaneo.Value

        ' Incrementar la fila o cambiar de columna según sea necesario
        filaActual = filaActual + 1
        If filaActual > 47 Then
        
            ' Cambiar a la siguiente columna cuando se llegue al final de las filas
            columnaActual = IIf(columnaActual = "B", "D", "B")
            filaActual = 22
        End If
    Else
        ' El archivo no fue abierto desde ListBox
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        
        ' Verificar si ya se alcanzó el máximo de registros
        If filaActual > 47 Or (filaActual = 47 And columnaActual = "D") Then
            MsgBox "Se completaron los 52 registros disponibles para el primer triwall.", vbInformation
            TxtEscaneo.Value = ""  ' Limpiar la caja de texto después de alcanzar el límite
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' Insertar el dato escaneado en la celda correspondiente
        ws.Range(columnaActual & filaActual).Value = TxtEscaneo.Value

        ' Mostrar el dato en el ListBox
        ' ListBoxDatos.AddItem TxtEscaneo.Value

        ' Incrementar la fila o cambiar de columna según sea necesario
        filaActual = filaActual + 1
        If filaActual > 47 Then
            ' Cambiar a la siguiente columna cuando se llegue al final de las filas
            columnaActual = IIf(columnaActual = "B", "D", "B")
            filaActual = 22
        End If
    End If
    
    
    ' Limpiar la caja de texto después de procesar el escaneo
    TxtEscaneo.Value = ""

    ' Prevenir el comportamiento predeterminado de la tecla Enter (no salta al siguiente control)
    KeyCode = 0

    ' Volver a seleccionar automáticamente la caja de texto para continuar escaneando
    TxtEscaneo.SetFocus
    
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: No pongas todo tu código, pon solo las partes relevantes. ¿en qué parte del código sucede lo que comentas? ¿Probaste a ejecutarlo con F8 paso a paso para ver por qué sucede?